# Need help moving Wordpress Multisite from local host to my web hosting server

Tags: wordpress

I have encountered some dificulties moving my wordpress multisite from localhost to my webhosting server.I would appreciate if someone can post a tutorial how to do this step by step.I modified my wp-config and changed urls in posts table(guid column) to fit the domain name, but still not working.I may miss something.

Thanks in advance.Have a nice day.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen a lot of these issues and successfully fixed it by doing some Google search. Sometime it's really hard to find solution to the specific problem you are having, but there is always an answer.

First i would like to tell you that you can make this process easier by using some plugins like: backupbuddy or Duplicator.

But if you want to learn the steps to do that manually, here are the details:

I'm assuming that you already have a local Wordpress site running with full access and you also have a web hosting plan with access to their control panel.

You also need **FTP client** to transfer files over to your server, i use **FileZilla** it's free and comes with all functionality you need for this or any other uploading purpose.

1: Export Wordpress database from **phyMyAdmin**, to do that go to `http://localhost/phpmyadmin/` click on your wordpress database and now you will click on **export** from the menu. You will see **custom** option after you click **export** which gives more options, select **all tables** and use **gzipped** as preferred compression format. Now scroll down and press **Go** to download your wordpress database.

I'm doing the same thing while writing this so i don't make any mistake while explaining to you or anyone reading this.

2: Open the FTP client you have or download and install FileZilla, connect to your web hosting directory. Now the site uploading process starts, suppose you need the wordpress site to be on main url like example.com, in that case you will upload your wordpress files to **public_html** directory.

There are two windows within the ftp client the left one is mostly the local and right is remote, copy your wordpress files from local to remote which is your server.

3: It's now time to create MySql database on your online site.
Go to your web hosts control panel and in **mysql databases** create a new database, give it any name of your choice it doesn't matter.

Once the database is created scroll down to **MySql users** section and create brand new user for that database, next step is to setup **privileges**. Give that user all privileges.

4: Now import Wordpress database to your online site, in your control panel open **phpmyadmin** which is mostly under databases section, choose the database you created in step 3 now click on **import** tab, click **choose file** or browse and select the gzipped  file you exported from your local site. Click **import** and your databases will be imported.

5: This is part where most of the people makes mistake, be careful doing this. In this step you will change the site URL to go online. In the database we just imported look for **wp_options table** (I'm assuming that you haven't changed your database prefix for security reasons yet) click wp_options table and click **browse**.

Look under **option_name** field, look for siteurl. Now click Edit button in the same lane.
Another windows appears at this point which shows you the current site url most probably `http://localhost/something`. Type in your website address here like: http://tech-diggers.com

Save once you enter the correct site. Do the same thing for **Home** under **options_name** field. Change the siteurl to your site address for **home**.

6: At this point if you visit your website it must be giving some error, that's because the last part is still pending. Go to your ftp client and on remote site edit wp-config.php file. Enter database name, user id and password save and upload back to the remote directory.

You can test the site now by going to your `http://example.com/wp-admin`

Finally you have your working Wordpress site online, now it's time to grab some useful resources for Wordpress: [Best Web Hosting Service & Other Useful Resources for Bloggers](http://tech-diggers.com/best-web-hosting/)